# MS SQL to Excel - Timezones

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, datetime, timezone

I have

- an SQL Server 2012, where datetime fields are stored in UTC time
- an Excel File, that is integrated via ADO DB command objects to the SQL server
- a function to check the current system settings, which allows to see the current system's difference to UTC

I need to display dates/times in Excel in local time (varies).

Until SQL Server 2016 (which we can't currently upgrade to), there is no Timezone support built-in to T-SQL.

There are various options that are playing around in my head, but I can't decide which one is worth pursuing:
  - transmit the *current* time difference as a parameter to the Stored Procedure, and amend all date fields to apply that difference
  - retrieve the UTC times, and return the field(s) as a formula (so instead of return field, field, created, modified I might return field, field, =fnUtcToLocal(#created#)... and so on
  - retrieve UTC times, and use an adjacent formula (with QueryTable.FillAdjacentFormulas)

Regardless of the option, I've still got a problem left: When, for example, checking the system difference *now* in Excel when the user is in Eastern Standard Time, it is -5 hours. When my created date falls into the EDT time, the correction would still be -5 instead of -4 hours.

Does anyone have a smart idea on how I should approach this? Please let me know if any additonal detail is required.

Comment: After reading tons of material, it looks like implementing a solution in SQL is a waste of time. Maybe I can bridge the time to SQL 2016 (apparently Q3 this year) by doing sth quick and dirty on the frontend.

Comment: Will you know what timezone you will be converting to ahead of time?  If so you can use an SSIS package with a script component and the c# method TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc.

Comment: Yes, the reporting client is delivered to a specific person with a specific config, so I could send away client a with a setting for Eastern Time, and client b with a setting for Hong Kong time.
As mentioned, the clients are Excel based and don't have any write access. I could only manipulate queries or amend my stored procedures to accept additional parameters. Would your suggestion still work?

Comment: I would not use SSIS do deliver the reports since it would have to run the package every time someone ran the report.  You could add a column to the table for each timezone and run the SSIS package when populating the data then only pull the timezone that is applicable for your client (timezones available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx), however that feels kind of ugly.  If possible, I would try to have the reporting client convert the timezone using the workstation timezone ID but that would be in code and not in SQL.

Comment: Thanks very much, I feared as much. Looking forward to Q3 this year when SQL 2016 is hopefully production ready.